# Why PHP is not forbidding me from initializing class properties using heredoc syntax?

Tags: php, class, heredoc, variable-initialization, class-properties

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

As mentioned in the PHP manual :

> Heredocs can not be used for initializing class properties. Since PHP
>   5.3, this limitation is valid only for heredocs containing variables.

The above sentence is saying that class properties can not be initialized using heredoc syntax since **PHP 5.3**.

I'm using PHP 7.1.11 and initializing class property using heredoc syntax but I didn't get any error and the class property got initialized.

Why so?

Consider my below working code for it :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    class foo {
      public $bar = <<<EOT
                    barti
EOT;
    }

    $j = new foo();
    echo $j->bar;
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output of above code is

```
barti
```

Comment: `Since PHP 5.3, this limitation is valid only for heredocs containing variables.` Your example does not contain a variable so it doesnt count to the limitation mentioned.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt : Can you please prove this with some suitable working code example? What does actually mean by " heredocs containing variables"? Give me some example of such kind.

Comment: @user2839497 I guess the example you're looking for would actually be _non-working_ code in this case.

Comment: I posted an answer, which also contains that "non-working" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your source already points out `since PHP 5.3, this limitation is valid only for heredocs containing variables`. Your example code does not contain any variables, so it works as designed.

---

However, what **does not work** is using variables in the heredoc like shown below:

```
    class foo {
      public $bar = <<<EOT
                    barti $someVariable // nor does {$someVariable}
EOT;
    }

    $j = new foo();
    echo $j->bar;
```

This throws an error:

```
Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations in [...]
```

---

**NOTE**

This 'issue' does not come from heredocs. You cant initialize any class property to the result of a function or variable. Just try it without heredoc:

```
class foo {

  public $bar = $test;
}

$j = new foo();
echo $j->bar;
```

Executing this code throws the exact same error.

Comment: Do you mean when variable/s is/are used in class property initialization with the heredoc syntax PHP will throw fatal error? But, if a normal variable is  initialized with the heredoc syntax then PHP will not throw any error? In that case the variable(as well as escape sequence characters, if any) will get expand in between heredoc identifiers?

Comment: Its not a heredoc (only) thing. You cant just set properties to a variable or the result of a function. I´ll add it in my answer

Comment: I think this is a good place to note that a class constant can be initialized to include the value of an earlier defined class constant. For example `const FOO = "not ".self::BAR` works. It's the fact that variables are...well...variable that is the problem.